# Character "Hobo" and his saying in the film The Polar Express?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-polar-express

In the popular Movie  [The Polar Express](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Polar_Express_(film)), there is a character named [Hobo](http://polarexpress.wikia.com/wiki/Hobo). He is a strange man who lives on top of the Polar Express. And during a conversation with the hero boy he says **"I am the king of the North Pole"**.

So, my Questions are:

**Why does this Hobo character say he is the king of North pole? Also why is he said to be of "negativity" when he helps the other characters in the movie and before?**

[image]

Comment: Very similar question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111183/who-is-the-hobo/120278).

Comment: @Walt - Ha Ha , Yes , little similar with same image & same ref. site also :) but mine is not about his character instead abt. his saying. Nice find  ,Thanks.